# Make TortoiseGit not work on specific folders

Tags: windows, bash, git, tortoisegit

I have installed TortoiseGit on my Windows PC.

There is a directory on my pc (C:\SomeRepos), that has several git repositories underneath it. Those repositories are deleted or created by a script that runs on my PC based on some rules.

It seems that there are several times the script fails to delete the directory of a repository and I suspect the reason might be that tortoise also works on that directory as well.

I want to use tortoiseGit for all of the repositories on my PC, but I do not want it to interfere at all with the directory C:\SomeRepos.

Is this possible? Is there any good workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define exclude lists and directories in TortoiseGit settings:

https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-overlay

You could also change the way to overlay icons are calculated by setting Status-Cache to Shell or Shell-Extended.

Comment: Thank you @MrTux. I have followed these instructions. Thanks again.